# Docker base image: Is it a dependency for new custom image?

Tags: docker

I'm learning Docker and down the path I mixed up my thoughts.
Say I pulled ubuntu as a base image and i made a new image out of it. Is this base Image is a dependency to my new image or my new image copy the base image and build top of it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image typically contains several layers. Your new image will share some layers with the base image. If we see "image" and "layer" as different objects the answer to your question is yes and no. The image is independent (you don't need to have the base image around in order to use the image) but it shares the layers of the base image and adds some new layers on top of it.

This layer sharing happens under the hood. You don't have to deal with it explicitly. It has the nice side effect that a lot of disk space is saved, for example if you have several images based on the same base image.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this "layer" thing. Can you please help me out? And one more thing, you said "It shares the layers of the base image." so what if my base image get removed from the repo! will i have a broken image then?

Comment: The repo is smart enough to know that a certain layer is still used in another image and will not remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that will do for now. :)